# Rotate camera around offset to player position (third person shooter view)

Tags: camera, rotation, third-person-view

I'm trying to rotate my camera 'next to' the player object so that the player is not in the way of the screen-centered reticle. What I am trying to achieve is something like the targetting system of Fortnite, GTA 5 or Red Dead Redemption (or most third-person shooters), where the camera/player are offset slightly so that you can see directly in front of them.

My code so far allows me to rotate the camera about the player (`object` here) and it follows the player's position. I cannot figure out how to offset it.

```
public void update(final GameObject object)
    {
        this.newMouseX = Input.getMouseX();
        this.newMouseY = Input.getMouseY();

        final float dx = (float) (this.newMouseX - this.oldMouseX);
        final float dy = (float) (this.newMouseY - this.oldMouseY);

        // Rotate the camera on mouse move
        this.verticalAngle -= dy * this.mouseSensitivity;
        this.horizontalAngle += dx * this.mouseSensitivity;

        // Distances from side view
        final float horizontalDistance = (float) (this.distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.verticalAngle)));
        final float verticalDistance = (float) (this.distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.verticalAngle)));

        // Distances from top view
        final float xOffset = (float) (horizontalDistance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-this.horizontalAngle)));
        final float zOffset = (float) (horizontalDistance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-this.horizontalAngle)));

        this.position.set(object.getPosition().getX() + xOffset, object.getPosition().getY() - verticalDistance + VERT_OFFSET, object.getPosition().getZ() + zOffset);

        this.rotation.set(-this.verticalAngle, this.horizontalAngle, 0);

        this.oldMouseX = this.newMouseX;
        this.oldMouseY = this.newMouseY;
    }
```

[image]

This is the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, but I have solved it myself after multiple attempts at the maths. I had to modify `xOffset` and `zOffset` with the following:

```
final float D = 20f;
final float d = 2f;
final float xOffset = (float) ((d * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-this.horizontalAngle))) + (D * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - -this.horizontalAngle))));
final float zOffset = (float) ((D * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 - -this.horizontalAngle))) - (d * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-this.horizontalAngle))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your character object should have vectors representing its facing (forward, right, up). If you take the normalized right vector and multiply it by a scaling factor, you will create an offset vector. Add the offset to the player position and store it in a separate variable. This is where your camera will rotate around, roughly speaking. Don't forget to update the offset each frame.

Answer (score 0):

first thing, I didn't made any game in third person view yet. But as of camera follow it should be easy. What I do is:-

I creates a public vector 3 variable named offset and use that as it:-

```
void Update()
{
   transform.position = player.position; /* this script should be in camera
   object and player is a transform variable which you can assign */
   transform.position += offset;
}
```

then I will go in game view and change the value of offset to put it as of third person view. Then I will copy the values or remember them, will exit from game view and set that in the offset variable.
This is what I will do, I hope it also works for you. You can use any function for moving camera just remember the logic behind it.